# What would be the best option to pass object ID to a subset of vertices in a vertex buffer?

Tags: directx

I'm building my engine with the assumption that the entire contents of a single vertex buffer is to be drawn in one call with no state changes in between. The issue I'm having is that the buffer will contain many different meshes with different textures on them.

I need some way to tell the pixel shader which texture to pick. So far i see 2 options:
a) set up a sort of register in a constant buffer that would have an array of vertex id's and object id's, for example: vertex ID > 123 corresponds to object 3, vertex id > 423 corresponds to object 4 etc. The problem with this approach is that for one i could only fit a maximum of 4096 meshes in the buffer. Second there would be a noticable performance hit since the vertex shader would have to shuffle through all the values until it finds where it belongs.

b) have the object ID as a part of vertex buffer to be fed to the IA. The problem i have with this is that it just seems such a waste to write a number over and over throughout the length of a mesh.

Is there any way to define a variable offset for an IA element so i'd have to write the mesh id just once and have it passed on to x number of verts? Or any other way you can think of?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the object ID as part of your vertex format and put the object id in per vertex data, but you have to measure the performance impact on memory bandwidth consumption of this.